# Using isNan and Date.parse to check if a date is valid

Tags: javascript, date

I'm building something similar to a date picker/ calendar, and I'm using the following expression, to get the data from the input:

```
 isNaN(Date.parse(event.target.value)) ? date = new Date() : new Date(event.target.value);
```

to verify if is a valid date.

But doesn't seems to work, I always get today date.

I saw other solutions regarding calendars, but I don't want to use regex or moments.js or other dependencies. Because I do also a check on the back end, and use a specific format.

My question is more related why isNaN not working as expected, than to date picker.

I'm using the following pattern for the date: 12/11/2014

If I'm trying alos this format 'Aug 9, 1995' and after I use:

```
day = date.getDate();
```

I get an error: `"TypeError: date is undefined"`. Date.parse returns `807915600000`

I console.log `event.target.value` and is ok, no issues on getting the value.

Comment: give us some sample date strings that you're parsing. some that work and some that don't maybe?

Comment: what the format of the event.target.value?? long? string?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TKoL - I added the format that I use

Comment: I just tested that format, and your code works fine with that format. `x = isNaN(Date.parse(event.target.value)) ? date = new Date() : new Date(event.target.value);` where `event = {target: {value: '12/11/2014'}}`

Comment: I did a mistake in ternary I should have ? date = new Date(), but date= at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issues, it was not related to the Date but in the ternary operator.

I used  `? date = new Date()` instead of using `date =` as a variable that get the return.